# How can i feature detect in case MUI components break?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

Some of my components are breaking if its a really old browser (built in browser from a QR scanning app). And i would like to feature detect it.

So components that break are the Slider Component and the Switch Component. How could I feature detect this?
Is there a feature that MUI uses on all of its components that i could detect if its supported by browser? Cant seem to find anything online

[Link to broken components](https://imgur.com/a/s4ka2zu)